# javaws always loads 32 bit libraries even when client is 64 bit

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a jnlp file that passes JaNeLa, so it has no errors. The web start app runs fine on Linux and Windows 32 bit. It fails to run on Windows 64 bit. I devised the following test  to determine if javaws is loading the correct native libraries:

- change the name of the library files in the jnlp file to files that do not exist
- load the app to force a file not found error to see which file it is trying to load

Here is the jnlp stub (the rest of the file is fine... trust me):

```xml
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <nativelib href="swt-4.2-win32-x86_64.jarx" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="swt-4.2-win32-x86.jarx" />
    </resources>
```

Javaws tries to load the 32 bit library which means it does not recognize arch="x86_64"

So I changed the first line to:

```xml
<resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
```

But javaws still tries to load the 32 bit file. Whatever is going on, the architecture of my os is not being detected.

I have trawled a great deal before posting. Some say use amd64 and some say use x86_64 but neither work. It is nearly impossible to find an exhaustive OS/arch list.

Question: how to make javaws load the 64 bit binaries when requested from a 64 bit machine?

Edit:

I can locate the correct file by putting the following tag in the jnlp file:

```xml
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86\ ">
```

So there is an arch value that starts with "x86 ". But if I put "x86 64" it does not work. So there is a space, but what comes after the space? And doesn't Oracle publish a list of acceptable values for this field?

Comment: What value for `os.arch` is seen when that machine is pointed to [this page](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=os.arch&format=TSV)?  I run a 32 bit JRE on a 64 bit machine and see `os.arch x86`. in the text area at the top.

Comment: So far, I've only encountered "x86" for 32 bit and "amd64" and "x86_64" for 64 bit JVMs. (Note the underscore.) A space is used to separate different options, so in fact arch="amd64 x86_64" should match all 64 bit JVMs, but this doesn't work in my case... I have no idea why, leaving me with two resources elements, one with arch="amd64", another with arch="x86_64", without os attribute.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I assumed that since I was running windows 7 pro 64 bit that my JVM was also 64 bit. Not. The first time your browser points at a javaws application, it installs the JVM for you. And the JVM installed depends on your browser. Windows 7 64 bit comes with IE 32 bit pre-installed, which is javaws was fetching the 32 bit lib. So the problem of choosing correct native library with respect to the architecture seems solved, at first glance. There are still problems, but this is not one of them.